# Vector space of polynomials

Tags: vector-spaces

Do all polynomials $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ with a root at $x=1$ form a vector space? Do the coefficients $(a,b,c,d)$ form a vector space?

My reasoning:
Since $x=1$ is a root, we can't have $(a,b,c,d)$ all zeros. The space doesn't include the zero-matrix. Hence, it's not a vector space

Suppose, 
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ = polynomials of form $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ with root at $x=1$
$h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$
Since $x=1$ is a root, $f(1) = 0$ and $g(1) = 0$. $h(1) = f(1) + g(1) = 0$ ($h(x)$ also has a root at $x = 1$)

I'm not sure about the zero matrix in this case. What is considered as "zero matrix" in polynomials?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: No. If you mean by "zero matrix" the zero *vector*, I don't understand why you think the set of polynomials with root at $1$ does not contain the zero vector. The zero vector $(0,0,0,0)$ corresponds to the zero polynomial and is certainly also $0$ at $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For a polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ having a root at $x=1$ is equivalent to have $a+b+c+d=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The zero vector in this case is $(0,0,0,0)$. This corresponds to the polynomials $p(x) = 0$. You have $p(1) = 0$ hence $p$ is in the set of all polynomials that are zero at $1$. So your set *does* contain the zero vector.

You have already shown that the set is closed with respect to addition and now we know that it also contains the zero vector. The [only thing that remains to be verified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition_and_useful_characterization_and_subspace) is that it is also closed with respect to scalar multiplication.